# trying to submit pyspark job by spark rest api but getting connection refused

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using PySpark version 3.5.0 on Ubuntu. I am trying to submit job via the Spark Rest API using `curl -X Post`.
My file is at location '/home/arbind/spark/arbind/practice/masterslave1.jar'

My Spark master is running at port 7077 and at UI its URL is 'http://arbind-sha:8080/'

I did this

```
curl -X POST http://Arbind-SHa:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{                                 
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "" ],                                                   
"appResource" : "/home/arbind/spark/arbind/practice/masterslave1.jar",
"clientSparkVersion" : "3.5.0",
"environmentVariables" : {
"SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},                   
"mainClass" : "Test",                                                                                 
"sparkProperties" : {                                                
"spark.jars" : "/home/arbind/spark/arbind/practice/masterslave1.jar",
"spark.app.name" : "Test",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
                                      
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
"spark.master" : "spark://Arbind-SHa:7077"
} 
}'
```

but I am getting this error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to Arbind-SHa port 6066 after 0 ms: Connection refused

Comment: Have you checked if your IP has access to the databricks resource? try `ping <databricks workspace url>`. If this works, then the PAT token you're using to run the job doesn't have run access to the job.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the below line in your spark-defaults.conf
You can find it in `$SPARK_HOME/spark/conf`

```
spark.master.rest.enabled true
```

Then you can do the following:

```
bash $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh

bash $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://192.168.1.1:7077
```

Then try localhost:8080

[image: spark-server]

Comment: i did have added this **spark.master.rest.enabled true** in my  $SPARK_HOME/spark/conf spark file but then also getting same error.

Comment: can you ping the rest endpoint like     **ping -p 6066 Arbind-SHa**           .... also can you please paste the screenshot of spark-ui ( the home page of the spark UI )